# PHP: $_GET contains variables not in $_REQUEST

Tags: php

When I do `print_r($_GET)` I see 4 variables, one of which is not seen in `print_r($_REQUEST)`. On this page I have a relevant .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^de/something/(.+)/(.+)/$ /something/something_darkside.php?URLpage=rental&URLcategory=$1&URLsubcategory=$2 [NE]
```

The variables from this rule (URLpage, URLcategory, URLsubcategory) are all present as REQUEST variables. So I'm wondering where the extra GET variable comes from - could be through register globals?

EDIT: the additional parameter is ID with a numeric value (ex 2256) which is used to retrieve records from the DB.

EDIT2: ok the page now loads ok after turning register globals ON. I'm still struggling to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: And what is the additional parameter?

Comment: OP edited, it is a numeric ID value

Comment: in your htaccess you are passing only 3 variable only, so you are getting 3

Comment: JapanPro - ok but where does the 4th one in GET come from?

Comment: Off-topic, but I love the "Something-something dark side" reference!

Comment: Hmm something _inserting_ in the `$_GET` array? Evil... wish there was a 'make it read only' ini-setting, but atm. thats only possible by replacing it with a read-only object afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone mutated `$_GET` somewhere in the app.